# Defining an infinitely long cylinder.

Tags: general-topology

> Question
>   Define an infinitely long cylinder.
>
> Definition: Quotient topology
>
> Let $\left ( X,\tau \right )$ be a topological space.
>   Let ~ be an equivalence relation on X and let $X^{*}$ be he collection of equivalence classes. 
>   Let 
>   $\pi: X\rightarrow X^{*}$ be the map taking each point to its equivalence class, i.e. $\pi\left ( x \right )=\left [ x \right ]$.
>
> The quotient topology $\tau^{*}$ on $X^{*}$ is the collection of sets 
>   $U \subseteq X^{*}$ such that $\pi^{-1}\left ( U \right ) \in \tau$.

I am having a bit of problem beginning this question.
A cylinder has a disc at the end. So perhaps there should be an 
$S^{1}=\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ we could work from?

However, any useful hints to kickstart me would be utmost helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question, exactly? (Also, what does "has a 1-sphere area" mean?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have edited the question.

Comment: An infinitely long cylinder doesn't have any ends! It is defined by $\mathbb{R}\times S_1$.

Comment: I apologise. But that's what the question on my notes asked for . I typed word for word.

Comment: I thought his question was the title. "Define an infinitely long cylinder."

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see what's the confusion. I shouldn't have used the title as a proxy for my question. Editing the OP now.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of "cylinder" is incorrect: a cylinder does not have "caps" at the end. It should just be the "tube" part. (As a side note, you shouldn't write e.g. "$S^1=[0, 1]$" - "$S^1$" is the standard notation for the $1$-sphere, that is, the unit circle. In your previous edit, what you described as "$1$-sphere" is actually called a "$2$-disc" or "$2$-ball" - an $n$-sphere is the boundary of a $(n+1)$-ball. The "$n$" refers to the dimension of the object - so a circle is one-dimensional, even though it "lives" most naturally in two-dimensional space, and the cap at the end of a cylinder is two-dimensional.)

Intuitively, you can form an infinite cylinder by taking $\mathbb{R}^2$ and "rolling it up". The point of the question is to make this precise by formalizing it as a quotient space construction. HINT: let's say I roll the plane along the $x$-axis, and wind up with a cylinder with circumference $1$. Note that the points $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$ wind up "overlapping." Do you see, in general, which points overlap with which other points?

Comment: Let me give this some thought.

Comment: Yes I do see it geometrically. Suppose the glueing occurs at all points along the boundary (0,y) and (1,y) for y in the reals. This produces a long cylinder and stretches as far as the y-values goes.
So, (0,0)~(1,0), (0,1)~(1,1),...
However, I understand the need to formalise this but am still familiar with using the definition of quotient space to do so.